# Get ID of custom element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I am creating a tampermonkey script for Google Earth that will hide the toolbar when you press a key. One of the elements that is supposed to be hidden looks like this:

```html
<earth-toolbar id="toolbar" role="toolbar">...</earth-toolbar>
```

I am trying to hide it using this code:

```
document.getElementById('toolbar').style.display = 'none'
```

Note that it also does not work in the console.

However, I get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at HTMLDocument.eval

Is it possible to access a custom element without modifying the code that actually created it, and if so what is it?

Comment: try to debug, try to run document.getElementById('toolbar'), check what it returns, an element ! or not!!

Comment: @DupinderSingh I tried it and it throws the same error.
>Note that it also does not work in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#toolbar` is within a `#shadow-root`, so you must access the `.root` property of that parent in order to find elements inside of it:

```
document.querySelector('earth-app').root.querySelector('#toolbar').style.display = 'none';
```

https://earth.google.com/web/

Comment: Thanks for telling me what the shadow DOM is!