# How can I programmatically click on elements using custom event listeners?

Tags: javascript, automation, event-listener, tampermonkey, shadow-dom

I am looking to automate tasks on Chase Bank's website but I am facing challenges accessing elements prefixed by `mds`, like `mds-button`, using `document.querySelector()` and `document.getElementById()`. These methods return `null` for all such elements on the page.

I have observed event listener functions present, but they do not respond to my attempts like this:

```js
const customEvent = new Event('click-brand_bar_hamburger_menu');
window.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

How can I, for example, programmatically trigger a click on the hamburger menu using Tampermonkey?

Comment: You should include the actual html in your question, as well as the context in which your code is being executed.

Comment: @mykaf Thank you for the suggestion. I just tried to edit the post; it's not my code of course, Adding the source exceeded the SO post size limit. I am not sure how helpful it will be out of context to anyone wishing to help.

Comment: We don't need the entire source, just a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can take a guess as to what the actual source is, but there are infinite ways our guess could be wrong and not include the actual problem.

Comment: @mykaf the problem is that this is not a typical software development problem that can be reproduced independently. It requires logging into a specific website and interacting with it. I just answered my own question using a much more sensible approach based on some more reading.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/55896379 and its duplicates

Answer (score 2):

According to [jcunews1](https://www.reddit.com/r/GreaseMonkey/comments/os5qnp/how_can_i_find_the_function_triggered_when/), on websites that use complex UI frameworks, many event handlers are local functions and not directly accessible from a global context. Therefore, it may require significant effort to obtain a reference to the specific function if you intend to call it directly.

In cases like this where accessing the function directly proves challenging, an alternative approach involves automating the click event by instead invoking Tampermonkey's click() method on the relevant elements.

However, in this case, the element itself is also inaccessible, which means it is likely encapsulated in a shadow root. If the shadow root is open, it is possible to access the element.

To find the shadow root, open Chrome's devtools, hit <kbd>F1</kbd>, and enable the "Show user agent shadow DOM" option.

[image]